I am experiencing segementation fault in C++ using for loop?
My code is experiencing a segmentation fault, even though I tried to bound my input parameters as I believed that inputs are the reason of array out of bound errors.
Can someone please help me realize where I am going wrong?
CODE :
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string words[9] = {"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};
    int numbers[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int input_a , input_b;
    cin >>input_a>>input_b;
  
    for( int i = input_a - 1 ; i <= 9;i++) {
        cout << words[i]<<endl;
    }
    if(input_a % 2 == 0){
        cout << "even"<< endl;
    }
    if (input_b % 2 == 0){
        cout << "even" << endl;
    }
    
    else{
        
        cout << "odd" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

Test INPUT
8
11

Expected OUTPUT
eight 
nine
even
odd


Remember that array indexes are zero-based. So an array of nine elements will have indexes in the range 0 to 8. You use index 9 in your loop. That is out of bounds, and lead to undefined behavior.

Please look at that  i <= 9 condition and think about what it means.

Not to mention that there's no validation for input_a to make sure it's in range.

i <= 9 will make the loop access the 10:th element in the array. There are only 9 elements in the array.

Unrelated: Use std::array instead of c-style arrays.
